# Condition to check a specific value from table asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```c#
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
con.Open();
string selstatus = "select status from Status where c_email=@c_email";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selstatus, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_email", Session["user"].ToString());
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string value = Session["user"].ToString();
DataRow[] row =dt.Select(value);
sda.Fill(ds);
sda.Fill(dt);
if(row!=null){
  Label13.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["status"].ToString();
}else{
  Label13.Text = "No response from mechanic";
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I have been finding way to check a specific email id exist in the table. But I can't query what is the correct format to do so. I just need that if a specific email id is available then a message should be displayed.

Comment: Are you recieving any erros

Comment: Trying to extract values from a datatable before even attempting to fill it cannot end well

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the DataAdapter, DataTable etc. Simply count the number of records

```
select count(1) from Status where c_email=@c_email
```

and then on the `SqlCommand` just use `ExecuteScalar`:

```
string selstatus = "select count(1) from Status where c_email=@c_email";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selstatus, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_email", Session["user"].ToString());
var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
// if count=0 the email doesnt exist
```

Comment: i want to check a specific value sir.

Comment: @TazimShaikh I'm sorry but I dont understand what that means.

Comment: sir, thank you so much. I have found out the solution.